# Control number of fft coefficients

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, fft

I have a signal of 5000 points `x` and `y`
When I use the discrete fourier transform manually, it is possible to create a list of coefficients controlling the number of coefficients, and the more coefficients, the greater the approximation of the original signal.

In the example below there is a signal of `5000 points` that after going through the DFT generated a list with `201 coefficients`.

But when using the `fft()` function I can't control the amount of coefficients.

Is there any way to use `numpy` or `scipy`, or their `fft functions` to generate the same 201 coefficients, instead of generating 5000 coefficients?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from math import tau
from scipy.integrate import quad_vec
from scipy.fft import fft

def f(t, t_list, x_list, y_list):
    return np.interp(t, t_list, x_list + 1j*y_list)

N = 5000
t_list = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, N)

r = (((0.0*np.pi<=t_list) * (t_list<=0.5*np.pi)) * 1/np.cos(t_list-0.25*np.pi) +
    ((0.5*np.pi<t_list) * (t_list<=1.0*np.pi)) * 1/np.cos(t_list-0.75*np.pi) +
    ((1.0*np.pi<t_list) * (t_list<=1.5*np.pi)) * 1/np.cos(t_list-1.25*np.pi) +
    ((1.5*np.pi<t_list) * (t_list<=2.0*np.pi)) * 1/np.cos(t_list-1.75*np.pi))

# create de signal a square form
x_list, y_list = np.cos(t_list) * r, np.sin(t_list) * r

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 5))
ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.plot(x_list, y_list)

print('x length list: ', len(x_list)) #5000 points
print('y length list: ', len(y_list)) #5000 points

order = 100 # -order to order i.e -100 to 100
# you can change the order to get proper figure
# too much is also not good, and too less will not produce good result

print("generating coefficients ...")
# lets compute fourier coefficients from -order to order
c = []

# we need to calculate the coefficients from -order to order
for n in range(-order, order+1):
    # calculate definite integration from 0 to 2*PI
    # formula is given in readme
    coef = 1/tau*quad_vec(lambda t: f(t, t_list, x_list, y_list)*np.exp(-n*t*1j), 0, tau, limit=100, full_output=1)[0]
    c.append(coef)

print("completed generating coefficients.")

c = np.array(c)

print('c length list: ', len(c))

# convert x and y to complex number
z = x_list + 1j*y_list

#get coeff of all element of list
coeff_fft = fft(z)

print('coeff_fft length list: ', len(coeff_fft))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
x length list:  5000
y length list:  5000
generating coefficients ...
completed generating coefficients.
c length list:  201
coeff_fft length list:  5000
```

[image: matplotlib]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DFT of N samples has N values. Any less and the transform wouldn’t be reversible. But of course you can compute individual elements of the transform.

The FFT (which you use when you call `fft()`) is a fast algorithm to compute the DFT. It is fast because it computes the full transform, not individual elements.

I am not aware of a function in a standard library that computes individual values of the DFT. But as you’ve shown, it is easy to write such a function. So either manually compute those 201 values as you do now, or compute the full DFT using `fft()` and pick out the values you need. Which one is faster depends on how many values you need and how many samples you have.